# Unable to login via Facebook (Parse): error code 251

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I have an app in the App Store which is using Parse and automatically creates anonymous users (I set [PFUser enableAutomaticUser]). So now I have several thousands of users in a Parse users table.

Now I'm trying to implement full profiles and convert anonymous users to non-anonymous by calling:

```
[PFFacebookUtils linkUser:currentUser permissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"] block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {
            //some logic
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }
    }];
```

BTW I've also tried:

```
        [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"] block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (!user) {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");                
        } else if (user.isNew) {
            NSLog(@"User signed up through Facebook!");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"User logged in through Facebook!");
        }
    }];
```

But in both cases I get an error: 251 - The supplied Facebook session token is expired or invalid.

What I've already tried:

- Logout anonymous user
- Refresh session
- Close and re-auth session

[image: FB app settings]

Nothing here works for me. Does anyone know what to do in this case? How do I correctly convert anonymous user to non-anonymous?

Comment: can u show the full error

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik `Printing description of error:
Error Domain=Parse Code=251 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 251.)" UserInfo=0x1744638c0 {error=The supplied Facebook session token is expired or invalid., code=251}`

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the problem is your Facebook App configuration.

Please go to your Facebook App settings (Advanced section) https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_FB_APP_ID/settings/advanced/

You should have enabled the option "Native or desktop app?" When you do so, you'll have other option with the message "Is your App Secret embedded?" The error 251 on iOS only comes up when you enable this second option because your app secret is not embedded so the token is invalid.

Please go to your settings and make sure the option "Is your App Secret embedded?" is NOT enabled.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for explanation but as it is shown on a screenshot all those settings are set as you suggested.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I tested this yesterday and it worked for me. I would suggest to double-check the following: 1. Bundle ID (FB iOS settings) 2. FB App ID and Secret ID at Parse settings 3. Users in your database that already have the Facebook profile linked (check that it's not already linked to another User) 4. SDK versions (try to use the last SDK of Parse and Facebook)

Answer (score 0):

verify your fb dev account at "Approved Items" > "Login Permissions" must be the same as you requesting in your permissions array in your code. In my case I am using the new API 2.0.

Hope you help it.

Regards from Cancun
[image: Login permissions FB]

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that i copied the App Secret when it was in dots, click on the show button in your Developer Settings and copy the string in there on to Parse.

Hope it helps.